# “Compile error: the variable has not been defined” using call function

Tags: excel, vba, method-call

I have a macro that opens a web page, assigns certain variables and then calls another procedure using the `Call` function. I would need to use some of the variables defined in the first procedure (for example `numberOfPages`) in the second procedure but I get the following error:

> Compile error: the variable has not been defined

Can someone please tell me what the error is and how to solve it? I detail below both procedures.

```vb
Sub test()    
    Dim element As IHTMLElement
    Dim elements As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim numberOfPages As Double
    Dim html As HTMLDocument

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "https://cebra.com.ar/category/73/Juego-de-Construccion.html"

    Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Application.StatusBar = "Loading Web page …"
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Set html = ie.document
    Set elements = html.getElementsByClassName("container")
    Set ElementCol = html.getElementsByTagName("a")
    numberOfPages = ie.document.querySelectorAll(".setPage").Length

    'MsgBox numberOfPages

    For Each ele In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("li")
        For Each element In elements
            If element.className = "container" Then
                'Do something
                Call procedure
            End If    
        Next element    
    Next
    MsgBox "Done"    
End Sub
```

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub procedure()    
    MsgBox numberOfPages

    'I want to use the internet explorer opened and this variable to do something
End Sub
```

Comment: You are going to need to define your Sub Procedure to pass in variables by reference or value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Karlomanio said, you need to pass variables to your sub-procedure (and please don't call it "procedure").

Here's your code, adjusted to make `numberOfPages` work:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub WebProcedure(numberOfPages as Long)

    MsgBox numberOfPages

    'Do something here based on the number of pages

End Sub
```

This would be called using the following line in your `test()` sub:

`WebProcedure numberOfPages`

Comment: Thank you very much! It works perfectly with one variable, but how can I pass more than one variable? Thanks again!

Comment: If it's a small number of variables, just add them to the function definition, e.g.: `Public Sub WebProcedure(numberOfPages as Long, varSomethingElse as Variant)`. If it's a bunch of variables, you can pass them in via an array of variables or a collection. At that point, though, it's probably an indication that you should be breaking your functions into smaller pieces for re-usability and debugging.

Comment: Thank you @SmrtGrunt, there are a small number of variables. I tried to add them in the function definition as you said but I get the following error message: "compilation error: the argument is not optional". Any idea? Thanks a lot!

Comment: After you add the variables to your function definition (and, I assume, use them in the function), you need to call the function appropriately. Like this: `WebProcedure numberOfPages, varSomethingElse`